# How to set Slack bot presence "online" when using Events API

Tags: bots, slack-api, slack

I have a bot for Slack implemented using RTM (https://api.slack.com/rtm) which works well but requires WebSocket connections for each user active all the time. After rewriting it using new Events API (https://api.slack.com/events) the bot works well too but appears "away" all the time. Apparently Slack determines bot's status by checking WebSocket connection which is not good as my goal is to use Events API only. Is it possible to use Events API and make a bot appear "online"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's one of the two reasons that we don't move to Events API for our bot. The second is that typing events are not send with Events API.

For what we know (dev4slack community, Slack's direct contacts), Slack works at make able to indicate online presence without the RTM, for bots using Events API. That seems essential, without that, Events API seems to be a half solution.

Answer (score 1):

Now with the RTM gone. Slack announced that the only way to toggle your bot presence is via the [app management page](https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status#bot_presence).

Official Tweet [here](https://twitter.com/SlackAPI/status/812376744883720196).